# Вызов JS функции Date() в jQuery методе val()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем, привет! Коллеги помогите решить проблему. Суть проста, надо менять значение INPUT`ов по нажатию на соответствующие кнопки. Вот [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsWa/) накидал примерный код, с комментариями. У меня не получилось воспользоваться в методе val() JS функцией для работы с датой.

**!!!Дополнил** свой [костыль](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsWa/2/). Первое число текущего месяца я получил, осталось получить последнее число текущего месяца. Какой алгоритм будет?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsWa/1/
не понял логику с "первый день текущего месяца" - если он и так первое число. 
или вам надо день недели указать? или еще что

Comment: @Fantyk, а отформатировать дату как-то можно? вот примерно такого формата dd-mm-yyyy. Надо дату обрабатывать, а у вас я так понимаю, работа с числами? Можно ли как-то в методе val() вызвать обычную JS функцию Date()?

Comment: разве трудно сделать небольшую функцию и вызывать потом .val(formatDate('start'))

Comment: было бы проще видеть то, что вы хотите... И вы можете всегда склеить нужную строку применив  
.getDate(), .getMonth() + 1, .getFullYear()

Comment: вэйтинг плиз друзья, сейчас попробую...

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat скорее всего один из сотен плагинов на эту тему)) можно погуглить ISO формат даты - в ту же сторону.

Comment: @Fantyk, @Konstantin Choporov, @eicto, @Zhukov Roman, я дополнил свой вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста как быть дальше, я там в коде самого костыля комментарий поставил. http://jsfiddle.net/HMsWa/2/

Comment: берите первое число следующего месяца 00:00 и отнимайте 1 секунду

Comment: а можно как-то в примерчеке отобразить, пожалуйста...?

Comment: `Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();` - вот такой трюк можно использовать для получения количества дней в месяце.